# SQL Syntax Error Missing Operator MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to run a query that will update a field in one table if a field in another table is equal to test. Here is the code:

```
UPDATE Table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 
ON t1.Field1 = t2.F_Name
SET t1.Field4 =
    (CASE 
        WHEN t2.PlayField = 'test' THEN 'test' 
        ELSE 'No test' 
    END);
```

However, I always receive a `Syntax Error (missing operator)` when I run it. Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: `CASE ... WHEN` is not supported in Access SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want to understand the issue..Your SQL :

```
UPDATE Table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 
ON t1.Field1 = t2.F_Name
SET t1.Field4 =
    (CASE 
        WHEN t2.PlayField = 'test' THEN 'test' 
        ELSE 'No test' 
    END);
```

MS Access doesn't support the `CASE` statement. It looks like SQL Server, not MS Access.

You could try:

```
 SET t1.Field4 =
IIf([t2].[playfield]='test','test','No test');
```

This basically says: Set `t1.Field` = If `t2.PlayField = 'Test'`, we will use the word 'test', if it doesn't we will use 'No Test'.

Answer (score 2):

`CASE ... WHEN` is not supported in Access SQL.  Use `IIf` instead.

```sql
UPDATE Table1 AS t1 INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 
ON t1.Field1 = t2.F_Name
SET t1.Field4 =
    IIf(t2.PlayField = 'test', 'test', 'No test');
```

Comment: Hey!  You changed your answer.  I swear that `IIf` expression was not in there.

Comment: I was proving my logic in my own database first haha, I am rusty in Access

Answer (score 0):

If the question is related to MS Access database engine...

Have a look here: [MS Access 2003: Update Query that updates values in one table with values from another table](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/update2.php)

Your query should look like:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET TableName.Field1 = (SELECT AnotherTable.Field2
                        FROM AnotherTable
                       WHERE AnotherTable.Field3 = TableName.Field2)
WHERE (<<condition>>);
```

`CASE WHEN ... END` statement is only possible to use within VBA. To achieve such as conditional result within query, use `IIF` function.

See: [IIF function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php)

Comment: Yes, but I want to know why my script isn't working just so I understand. I was able to update the tables with a simple where statement, but I just want to understand why it's saying I have a missing operator there